# Can you export a Typescript class with decorators as a plain class (without decorators)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-decorator

Lets say I have a class like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { IsString } from 'class-validator';
import { prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose';

@Injectable()
export class Human
{
    @prop({ unique: true })
    @IsString()
    readonly name: string;
}
```

The question is: can I export this class so that the receiving end gets it without the decorators, like this:

```
class Human
{
    readonly name: string;
}
```

I want to export the class (which has other dependencies for the decorators) so that the file importing it does not require the dependencies used for those decorators, such as nestjs, class-validator, and typegoose.

I'm trying to NOT write out "readonly name: string;" more than once.

Comment: Don't think that's possible without some kind of preprocessing. You could export a type or an interface derived from the class, but youldn't use these to instanciate objects. For that you need a constructor, but then you would also have to write the properties again.

Comment: @zett42 When I said I only wanted to write out the properties once, I meant in terms of defining the class/interface. Not when I'm creating new objects. When I create a new object of type Interface, I expect that interface to force me to implement that interface when im making the new object. And thats fine. I can live with that, and I can also live with adding a constructor for a class. Thats normal object oriented stuff.

With that said, can you show me an example of "export a type or an interface derived from the class" that would leave the decorator dependencies behind?

Comment: @zett42 sorry, I asked for an example because I already tried doing that but it wasn't working, but I figured out why so I can export it as a type without the dependencies. Oops! Thanks for the comment tho! If you dont mind, I will post it as an answer with an example.

Comment: To extract the interface: `export interface IHuman extends Human {};`. Feel free to  use that for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out, in part thanks to zett42.

You can define a `type` in typescript, so if you just make a type that is equal to the class, then export that type, you will effectively be exporting that class definition without decorators. You can also do it with `interfaces`, but types seem to be cleaner. However I'm not sure if types behave the same as interfaces, time to read the Typescript documentation!

With types:

```
export type THuman = Human;
```

With interfaces:

```
export interface IHuman extends Human {}
```

Comment: `export type` is creating a type alias for the class, which means the same class including the decorations AFAIK, you're not dropping them. `export interface I extends Class` should be the correct answer. AFAIK an interface extend only copies public member definitions on the object prototype.